# System.Action delegate ignore parameter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates

I have this:

```
public event Action<BaseCommodity> OnGatherActionSelected = delegate { };
gmp.OnGatherActionSelected += m_Worker.CharacterActions.StartGatherMaterials; // << takes a parameter
```

but now i want to use the event to call a method which takes 0 parameters

```
gmp.OnGatherActionSelected += ParentPanel.RedrawUI; // does not take parameters .. DOES NOT WORK :(
```

how can i do this?

Comment: If you want a handler without parameters, you should use `Action` instead of `Action<T>`

Comment: i mainly need the parameter, only in one single case i want to ignore the parameter and just call the method... i can't believe that there is no way to skip the parameter

Comment: So just ignore it using `obj.YourEvent += x=>yourMethod();` as Guffa and Charles offered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest option is to add a handler that takes the parameter and ignores it, delegating to the method you want to use:

```
gmp.OnGatherActionSelected += _ => ParentPanel.RedrawUI();
```

Comment: well, this was indeed easy ! THANK YOU !

Comment: This does indeed work well, thank you.  I still wonder if there's a 'better' way to structure the code, or If I'm overanalyzing.

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap it in a method that takes a parameter:

```
gmp.OnGatherActionSelected += x => ParentPanel.RedrawUI();
```